# How to draw colored text on QGraphicsScene?

Tags: c++, qt

I was looking for options like `QGraphicsTextItem::setPen()`, or even `QFont::setColor()` or `QFont::setForegroundColor()`. None of them exists.

How can I draw colored text on QGraphicsScene? I don't want to use `QGraphicsTextItem::setHtml()` and use HTML to do that (not sure if that's possible, though).

I'm using Qt 4.7.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for a combination of `setPlainText()` and  `setDefaultTextColor()`?

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qgraphicstextitem.html#setPlainText

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qgraphicstextitem.html#setDefaultTextColor

If not, I'm not sure I understand your question...

Answer (score 6):

```
scene.addText(tr("Hello World"))->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::white);
```

Answer (score 1):

QGraphicsTextItem has a `palette` method which returns a `QPalette` and `QPalette` has the setColor method which takes a role.

```
void QPalette::setColor ( ColorRole role, const QColor & color )

The role you want is

QPalette::Text  The foreground color used with Base. 
This is usually the same as the WindowText, in which case it must provide 
good contrast with Window and Base.
```

Comment: i can't find `QGraphicsTextItem::palette()`.